# How to define a header parameter's default value is in OpenAPI 3.0

Tags: swagger, openapi

I have an endpoint that accepts a PUT without a body. The PUT causes an event to trigger on the backend, and our API design team decided that PUT was the best RESTful verb for the method's purpose.

The problem is when our Swagger renders our .yaml file, the sample cURL command it displays fails to run from a command prompt. Apparently `curl` does not like to do a PUT without a body, unless it includes the header value:  `Content-Length: 0`. The method returns `200-OK` when called by the 'execute' button on the rendered page, but not from the generated curl command.

How do I add a default value in the OpenAPI Spec so the header would be included by the Swagger renderer when it generates the example curl command?

Here is an example of our method in the .yaml file:

```
'/{jobId}/start':
  parameters:
    - in: header
      name: Content-Length
      schema:
        type: string
  put:
    summary: Starts processing job
    tags:
      - Actions
    responses:
      '200':
        description: OK
    description: Starts processing job
```

I tried to use the `default` keyword but my editor (Visual Studio Code) indicates it's not a valid Property. And I cannot find anywhere in OpenAPI Specificiation on how to default a header parameter's value.

Answer (score 1):

If you define a parameter to your put method with the fromheader decoration and correct value it will generate what you want.
Example:

```
[HttpPut]
public Task<ActionResult> Put([FromHeader(Name = "Content-Length")] string foo = "0")
{
     // execute anything here               
     return NoContent();
}
```

edit:

My example generates openapi document the way you wanted it. I see a slight difference against your example. In my example parameters is part op de http operation (put). And default is part of schema.
In yaml this will look as:

```
'/{jobId}/start':
  put:
    summary: Starts processing job
    tags:
      - Actions
    parameters:
      - name: Content-Length
        in: header
        schema:
          type: string
          default: "0"
          nullable: true
    responses:
      '200':
        description: OK
    description: Starts processing job
```

In your example it is part of the path which is incorrect according: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/paths-and-operations/

Comment: I was thinking more about editing a yaml file directly. Our source does not generate the OpenAPI Spec, we follow the API First design methodology and handroll our Swaggers. We use the OpenAPI Spec as a "requirements doc" when writing the code behind.

Comment: Does this help then?
```
"/api/YourApiController": {
"put": {
        "parameters": [
          {
            "in": "header",
            "name": "Content-Length",
            "type": "string",
            "default": "0"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success"
          }
        },
      }
    },
```

Comment: I think we're talking different tech. I'm curious about how to markup a `.yaml` file and it looks like you're providing advice on `.cs` files.

Comment: It should not matter which way you use the openapi standard. In json or yaml the property names are the same only the notation differs. I generate the document from code. I understand you use it to document the api you want to build. 
I will edit my answer to be more correct an aligned to your question.

Comment: It's valid to put `parameters` at the `path` level - they then apply to all methods.  See section "Common Parameters": https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/